# Adding custom fields on the fly in JOOMLA 3.9

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, custom-field

I am trying to develop a hobby project based on https://www.themealdb.com/ api.

I am trying to create an article programmatically for https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata and I was able to create an article with:

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC')) {
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__)));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
    defined('DS') or define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$url = 'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=Arrabiata';

$response = json_decode(curlFnToGetResponseFromMealDB($url));

$meal = $response->meals;

$cat_mealdb_id = 233; // I have a function that gets the category
$tags= []; // I have a function that gets the tags

$args = [
    'title' => $meal->strMeal . '-' . uniqid(),
    'catid' => $cat_mealdb_id,
    'introtext' => '', //nl2br($meal->strInstructions),
    'fulltext' => '', //nl2br($meal->strInstructions),
    'tags' => $tags
];

$article_id = prepareArticle($args);

function prepareArticle($args) {
    $article = [
        'id' => !empty($args['id']) ? $args['id'] : null,
        'catid' => !empty($args['catid']) ? $args['catid'] : null,
        'title' => !empty($args['title']) ? $args['title'] : null,
        'alias' => !empty($args['alias']) ? $args['alias'] : null,
        'introtext' => !empty($args['introtext']) ? $args['introtext'] : null,
        'fulltext' => !empty($args['fulltext']) ? $args['fulltext'] : null,
        'state' => 1,
        'language' => '*',
        'tags' => !empty($args['tags']) ? $args['tags'] : [],
    ];
    $article_id = createArticle($article);
    return $article_id;
}

function createArticle($data)
{
    $data['rules'] = [
        'core.edit.delete' => [],
        'core.edit.edit' => [],
        'core.edit.state' => [],
    ];

    $basePath = JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_content';
    require_once $basePath . '/models/article.php';
    $config = [];
    $article_model = new ContentModelArticle($config);
    if (!$article_model->save($data)) {
        $err_msg = $article_model->getError();
        return false;
    } else {
        $id = $article_model->getItem()->id;
        return $id;
    }
}
```

This is working well. I was able to create an article. Now I need to create custom fields based on the meal.

In this case:

1. Create a field with name `penne rigate`, if not exists. (`penne rigate` is the `strIngredient1`)
2. Add the value of `strMeasure1` (`1` pound to that field)
3. Map the field to this created article.

How to create an article field and map it to the article?

Comment: As a personal preference, I return `null` when an error doesn't throw an exception so that I can use nullable return types (since php 7.1).  I commonly see code using `false`, but php doesn't have "falsible" types.  Although since PHP8, there is `mixed` which makes it okay.  Some good reads: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37033142/2943403 , https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/best-practice-return-types-php , https://php.watch/versions/8.0/mixed-type